# Case statement with undefined type? or Why date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a simple table to store name-value-pairs.

```
create table ifr_nvpairs
(
    name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    type char(5),
    string varchar(255),
    bit_value bit,
    int_value bigint,
    dec_value decimal(12,2),
    float_value float,
    date_value datetime,
    char_value varchar(255)

);
```

There is a constraint and triggers to ensure that an

```
insert ifr_nvpairs(name,bit_value) values ('bitValue',1);
```

results in

```
bitValue    BIT     1   true    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

I skip those here for brevety and give you some complete inserts:

```
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('bitValue', 'BIT  ', '1', true, null, null, null, null, null);
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('charValue', 'CHAR ', 'Hugo ist nett!', null, null, null, null, null, 'Hugo ist nett!');
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('dateValue', 'DATE ', '2020-01-13 00:00:00.000', null, null, null, null, '2020-01-13 00:00:00', null);
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('decValue', 'DEC  ', '8.15', null, null, 8.15, null, null, null);
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('floatValue', 'FLOAT', '3.14159', null, null, null, 3.14, null, null);
INSERT INTO "ifr_nvpairs" ("name", "type", "string", "bit_value", "int_value", "dec_value", "float_value", "date_value", "char_value") VALUES ('intValue', 'INT  ', '42', null, 42, null, null, null, null);
```

For convinience of the users I wanted to create a select which returns the value in the stored type.

My approach was

```
select 
    case type
    when 'BIT' then  bit_value  
    when 'INT' then  int_value  
    when 'DEC' then  dec_value  
    when 'FLOAT' then  float_value
    when 'DATE' then  date_value 
    when 'CHAR' then  char_value
    end result 
    from ifr_nvpairs where name='bitValue';
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there was an error. But the result is always a datetime.

Why? And is there possible construct in SQL to select an heterogen type?

TIA Jo

Comment: [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: There is a construct for a heterogeneous type -- `SQL_VARIANT`. It is hard to use appropriately, however, since it has no meaningful operations by itself (using it in T-SQL requires some awkward extracting with `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`), and a conversion is always necessary before you can do anything meaningful with it (so possibly dynamic SQL). Consuming it from clients is not necessarily convenient either.

Comment: Thank you. That was quick. The Datatype-Precedence link helped
The SQLVariant is something I will dig into.
Thank you.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement, in  SQL. Expressions have a defined type as others have explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL `select` query returns a fixed set of columns.  Each column has a fixed type, determined when the query is *compiled*.

A `case` expression returns a single type as well.  By the rules of type conversion, that type is generally the "most specific" (these are the rules of SQL).  With the plethora of types you have provided, the result of the rules appears to be a `datetime`.

You cannot return multiple different types in a single column unless you specify the value as a [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which is really just another type).

You cannot do what you want with regular SQL.  One possibility is dynamic SQL.  Another would be a different approach that didn't require such logic.

Comment: Thanks Gordon this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression uses [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the return data type:

> SQL Server uses the following precedence order for data types:
>
> 1. user-defined data types (highest)
> 2. sql_variant
> 3. xml
> 4. datetimeoffset
> 5. datetime2
> 6. datetime
> 7. smalldatetime
> 8. date
> 9. time
> 10. float
> 11. real
> 12. decimal
> 13. money
> 14. smallmoney
> 15. bigint
> 16. int
> 17. smallint
> 18. tinyint
> 19. bit
> 20. ntext
> 21. text
> 22. image
> 23. timestamp
> 24. uniqueidentifier
> 25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
> 26. nchar
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
> 28. char
> 29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
> 30. binary (lowest)

The type with the highest precedence will be returned, which in this case, is `datetime` (with a precedence of 6).

As for your question *"And is there possible construct in SQL to select an heterogen type?"*, as mentioned in the comments, `sql_variant` does exist, but I recommend against it. It has *very* few use cases and any comparisons require that the value is *explicitly* converted. As you can't use syntax like `CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(YourColumn,'BaseType'),YourColumn)` you would have to use dynamic SQL to do this, and you still can't have multiple data types in a single column.

If you need to display different data types, do so in different columns.